# MySQL query combining sums from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have the following query that is trying to generate a list of all clients, their projects, time spent on each project, total invoiced amount and total number of invoices.

```
SELECT
    c.name as client,
    p.name as project,
    SUM(t.hours) as hours,
    SUM(ci.amount) as invoice_amount,
    COUNT(ci.id) as number_invoices
FROM
    projects p
    INNER JOIN client_master c ON c.harvest_id = p.client_id
    INNER JOIN timesheet t ON t.project_id = p.id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN projects_contracts pc ON pc.project_id = p.id
    INNER JOIN contracts_invoices ci ON ci.contract_id = pc.contract_id
GROUP BY
    c.name,
    p.name
ORDER BY
    c.name, 
    p.name,
    t.hours
```

When I run the query, the "hours" are being calculated correctly but the sums/counts for invoice_amount and number_invoices aren't being joined contextually to the project but to the total number of invoices in the table. If I comment out one of the sum()'s then I get the proper value but not when they're both in.

**Expected Results**

Client A, Project 1, 1000, $10,000, 2

Client A, Project 2, 5000, $5,000, 1

Client B, Project 1, 100, $3000, 1

**Actual Results**

Client A, Project 1, 1000, $150,000, 20

Client A, Project 2, 5000, $50,000, 81

Client B, Project 1, 100, $83000, 12

I've tried messing w/ the grouping and join statements but haven't found success. Is there something simple I'm overlooking or do I need a total rewrite?

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Help me out here, I massively scaled this query down. What else would you expect to see?

Comment: When both sums are in, and incorrect, how are the values different from when you take one out? Is the correct value higher or lower than the incorrect one?

Comment: I thought I just did

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This may not be the best way, but I bet it works

```
SELECT
    c.name as client,
    p.name as project,
    t.hours as hours,
    ci.amount as invoice_amount,
    ci.count as number_invoices
FROM
    projects p
    INNER JOIN client_master c 
        ON c.harvest_id = p.client_id
    INNER JOIN (SELECT project_id, SUM(hours) AS hours FROM timesheet GROUP BY project_id) t
        ON t.project_id = p.id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN projects_contracts pc 
        ON pc.project_id = p.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT contract_id, SUM(amount) AS amount, COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS count FROM contracts_invoices GROUP BY contract_id) ci
        ON ci.contract_id = pc.contract_id
GROUP BY
    c.name,
    p.name
ORDER BY
    c.name, 
    p.name,
    t.hours
```

Comment: That seems to have done it. It produces several projects with null invoice amounts but that's fine as I can WHERE those out. Now... to try to throw the rest of the formulas back in....

Answer (score 0):

Since invoices are dependant on contracts, and contracts are optional (the left join), 
make that join also a left join.

```
SELECT
    c.name as client,
    p.name as project,
    SUM(t.hours) as hours,
    SUM(ci.amount) as invoice_amount,
    COUNT(ci.id) as number_invoices
FROM
    projects p
    INNER JOIN client_master c 
        ON c.harvest_id = p.client_id
    INNER JOIN timesheet t 
        ON t.project_id = p.id 
    LEFT JOIN projects_contracts pc 
        ON pc.project_id = p.id
    LEFT JOIN contracts_invoices ci 
        ON ci.contract_id = pc.contract_id
GROUP BY
    c.name,
    p.name
ORDER BY
    c.name, 
    p.name,
    t.hours
```

Comment: Thanks Sloan. When I'd done that before I got the following message MySQL said: Documentation

#1104 - The SELECT would examine more than MAX_JOIN_SIZE rows; check your WHERE and use SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 or SET MAX_JOIN_SIZE=# if the SELECT is okay

Comment: How many rows in the tables? What is MAX_JOIN_SIZE set to? Did you try to change it?

Comment: I added the SET SQL_BIG_SELECT=1 statement to the start of my query. This time it produced a result but the data was still not correct. I got CLIENT,PROJECT,148.92,142956.00,54 when I should have received CLIENT,PROJECT,148.92,$10,000, 3

Comment: See my questions to your original post. And the ones just above.

Comment: The biggest table is timesheet and only has 60K entries at this point. The rest of them have maybe 100 rows max. The numbers I'm getting are much higher than they should be. It's as if I'm getting sums of the whole table, not just for the project. Does that help?

Comment: In the invoices table, is there a column for the project ID? If so, add that in the join ... on clause.

Comment: describe `contracts_invoices`

id int(11) NO PRI  auto_increment 
contract_id int(11) NO    
client_name varchar(255) NO    
reference varchar(255) NO    
description text NO    
invoice_number varchar(20) NO UNI   
status varchar(50) NO    
quantity int(11) NO    
amount decimal(10,2) NO    
date_created datetime NO    
date_due datetime NO    
date_payment_received datetime NO

Comment: Please edit the question to add info like this instead of posting in a comment. Too hard to read.